# How to solve a below error to import merge from keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mse
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression,huber
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor

from util import shortWord_Dictionary, load_glove
```

These are the libraries i am trying to import but i am getting this error.

i have tried few other solutions such as importing subclasses like add and concentrate but still it is not working, Help me out here

Error is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-acc83d608c96> in <module>
     15 import tensorflow.contrib.keras as keras
     16 
---> 17 from util import shortWord_Dictionary, load_glove

~\Downloads\thesis-final\thesis-final\Microsoft\util.py in <module>
      6 from keras import initializers
      7 from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
----> 8 from keras.layers import Dropout, Embedding, Convolution1D, Dense, Merge
      9 from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
     10 from keras.models import Sequential

ImportError: cannot import name 'Merge' from 'keras.layers' (C:\Users\DARSHIT\Anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

`keras` doesn't have `Merge` layers, see the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/merge/). *Merge* is just the name that they gave to a subset of the layers, namely `Add`, `Multiply`, or `Average`.